# UiKit 2.18.0 Centering a child in IE9 uk-text-center

Tags: uikit, internet-explorer-9

The uk-text-center has changed in UiKit 2.18.0, it centers a child h1 but not a child ul. 
In order to center the ul I have to use the uk-flex-center, but this does not work in IE9.

```
<div class="uk-container uk-container-center uk-text-center">
<h1>Centered heading</h1>
<ul class="uk-subnav uk-flex-center">
...
.
```

The unordered list doesn't center in IE9, any ideas?